# How to handle "RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.java" file errors

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to install my app on my android device with "react-native run-android", but after installing "react-native-gesture-handler" I got an error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception" and got 15 errors in "RNGestureHandlerModule.java" in the node_modules folder.

I tried many times to link gesture handler. But nothing change appears in the errors.

```
/projects/gitlabstyleseject/kono-app-styles/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.java:4: error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
                                            ^
/projects/gitlabstyleseject/kono-app-styles/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactModule(name = RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.REACT_CLASS)
 ^
  symbol: class ReactModule

/projects/gitlabstyleseject/kono-app-styles/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:16: 
error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
                                            ^


Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
  uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    15 errors
```

Please, suggest me how to solve these errors. And I am new to react native.